# C++ CImg Library Error C2665 What is the problem?

Tags: c++, cimg

[cimg error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Pc39.png)

**Error code:**

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2665   'cimg_library::cimg::rand': none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types    goruntuisleme   C:\Users\sasniac\source\repos\goruntuisleme\goruntuisleme\CImg.h    25469

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace cimg_library;

int main()
{
 std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Comment: What command do you use to compile and link your code please?

Comment: where can i learn them ? :/

Comment: Sorry, I don't use or know any *"Integrated Development Environments"*, I prefer to use Makefiles and commas-line dev tools. Presumably your environment tells you the command it is executing when you click `"Build"`

Comment: @xeron  you are on windows or linux ?

Comment: i'm using windows

Comment: Does it work on linux @Landstalker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the library for you. It works after some modifications.

**1.** I suppose you downloaded the library from the official site ([here](http://cimg.eu/download.shtml))

**2.** Some cast to `(cimg_uint64 *)` are missing in the following functions:

```
 static double mp_u(_cimg_math_parser& mp) {
        return cimg::rand(_mp_arg(2),_mp_arg(3),(cimg_uint64 *) &mp.rng);
 }
```

Here:

```
static double mp_srand0(_cimg_math_parser& mp) {
        cimg::srand((cimg_uint64 *) &mp.rng);  
//...
}
```

Here :

```
 static double mp_g(_cimg_math_parser& mp) {
    cimg::unused(mp);
    return cimg::grand((cimg_uint64 *) &mp.rng);
 }
```

Comment: you are awesome !